# How to put giant parentheses around text

Tags: formatting

I want to make something that looks like this:

```
 /                \
|     Text goes    |
|     in here      |
 \                /
```

The whole thing should be centered in the page, with the text centered between the parentheses, and everything should be in the text font (I'm using XeTeX and the text font is different than the math font). I'd like the option to independently change the size of (1) the parentheses and (2) the text inside. Also, the fonts should be able to be made arbitrarily large, i.e., larger than `Huge`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I provide `\marquis[<scale factor>]{<width>}{text}`, where the scale factor is applied at the end.  The width is the (pre-scaled) text width, not counting the parens.

If you are unhappy with the width of the parens, let me know. One could also include all the `\vfill`ing inside the macro, if desired.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}
\newcommand\marquis[3][1]{%
\scalebox{#1}{$\scaleleftright{(}{\parbox{#2}{\centering #3}}{)}$}%
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
~\vfill\centering
\marquis[7]{2.2cm}{But as for me\ldots give me liberty or give me death!}
\vfill
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `\marquis[6]{2.3cm}{To be or not to be\ldots that is the question.}`

[image]

[image]

Here is the brace version:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}
\newcommand\marquis[3][5]{%
  \scalebox{#1}{$\scaleleftright{\{}{\parbox{#2}{\centering #3}}{\}}$}%
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
~\vfill\centering
\marquis[2]{3in}{\lipsum[4]}
\vfill
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

$\left\{\begin{tabular}{l}
line \\
one more line
\end{tabular}\right\}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Of course, you can use any kind of brackets.